# Why $\frac{d}{dx}(f(g)) = \frac{d(g^T)}{dx}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, partial-derivative

Reading about differentiation of matrices seems to state that, given $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(g)) = \frac{d(g^T)}{dx} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$$

(I think I might be wrong)

Why is the transposition needed? Moreover, does this mean that:

$\nabla f = \frac{d(f^T)}{dx} = (\frac{d(f)}{dx})^T$?

Comment: Product rule?${}$

Comment: If $g$ was of the form $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$, you wouldn't need to transpose. This is just so that the compositions make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note $f\circ g$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}$ so its derivative is a gradient vector. Depending on your convention, you would either write this gradient as a $m \times 1$ vector or a $1\times m$ vector. Appealing to the chain rule, your convention writes it as a $m\times 1$ vector :

$$D_x f\circ g=\underbrace{( D_xg^T)}_{m\times n}\underbrace{( D_g f)}_{n\times 1}.$$

The transpose is placed to be consistent within the convention you are working in. So your convention is set up such that putting a transpose on $g$ in  $ D_xg^T$ is needed to consistently write it as the desired $m\times n$ result.

If it helps, you can refer to matrix derivative rules on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus).
Personally, I do matrix derivatives quick and dirty: I apply derivative rules treating everything as a scalar, and then rearrange the order of the matrices or throw in transposes as needed for the dimensions to work out, and usually this approach gets me the right answer.